# Populate html to generate pdf openhtmltopdf?

Tags: java, openhtmltopdf

I want to create a table pdf so I using `openhtmltopdf` and I want to pass my list data from java to html then render to pdf. How can I do it?

```java
    private static Document html5ParseDocument(String inputHTML) throws IOException {
        org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc;
        System.out.println("parsing ...");
        doc = Jsoup.parse(new File(inputHTML), "UTF-8");
        System.out.println("parsing done ..." + doc);
        return new W3CDom().fromJsoup(doc);
    }

    private static void htmlToPdf(String inputHTML, String outputPdf) throws IOException {
        Document doc = html5ParseDocument(inputHTML);


        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputPdf);
        PdfRendererBuilder builder = new PdfRendererBuilder();
        builder.withUri(outputPdf);
        builder.toStream(os);


        builder.withW3cDocument(doc, System.clearProperty("user.dir").concat("/src/main/resources"));
        //builder.useUriResolver(new MyResolver());
        builder.run();
        System.out.println("PDF generation completed");
        os.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use template, let's say in your html you need to alter title, to do so;

In html

```
<title>
#{header}
</title>
```

And in your java code you can replace #{header} with header String ;

```
 inputHtml.replace("#{header}","New title");
```

Since your question is about list, you need to replace unique html label with your html string which you build inside of your java code.